# How to make my Ubuntu client a member of Windows Server 2012 Active Directory Domain to have interoperability?

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS client in my Windows Domain with Windows 2012 R2 Active Directory . I wanna make this ubuntu client a member of Windows domain and active directory . is there a clear solution or routine to do that ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is primarily about Microsoft Windows Active Directory and would probably be better suited for superuser or serverfault.

Comment: `realm --join {domain}` works for me

Comment: @roaima Removed...  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @jesse_b it's most definitely about Unix and Linux. The tools are mature, if not well understood.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the recommended solution for integrating modern Linuxes to AD is usually to use `sssd`.

[This is in official Ubuntu 18.04 documentation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html.en)

Make sure that the necessary packages are installed:

```
sudo apt install krb5-user samba sssd chrony
```

The installation of `krb5-user` will prompt for three things, using generic Kerberos names for them:

- realm name: when dealing with AD, this is the name of the AD domain, in UPPER CASE.
- name of the KDC server: this is one of the jobs of an AD domain controller.
- name of the Kerberos admin server: this is also the AD domain controller.

As Active Directory authentication is based on Kerberos, it requires that the system clock must be reasonably in sync with the AD servers' clocks. Usually, the AD servers will provide a NTP service for this purpose. If you use `chrony` for time synchronization, add the name of your (nearest) AD domain controller also to `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf`:

```
server my.ad.domain.controller.example
```

Samba is needed to perform some services related to AD authentication, even if you aren't sharing any Linux directories to Windows systems. Add this to the `[global]` section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]

workgroup = SHORT_NAME_OF_AD_DOMAIN
client signing = yes
client use spnego = yes
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
realm = AD.DOMAIN.FULL.NAME
security = ads
```

Replace `SHORT_NAME_OF_AD_DOMAIN` and `AD.DOMAIN.FULL.NAME` as appropriate.

Create a SSSD configuration file `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = AD.DOMAIN.FULL.NAME

[domain/AD.DOMAIN.FULL.NAME]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad

# Use this if users are being logged in at /.
# This example specifies /home/DOMAIN-FQDN/user as $HOME.  Use with pam_mkhomedir.so
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u

# Uncomment if the client machine hostname doesn't match the computer object on the DC.
# ad_hostname = mymachine.ad.domain.full.name
# Uncomment if DNS SRV resolution is not working
# ad_server = dc.ad.domain.full.name

# Uncomment if the AD domain is named differently than the Samba domain
# ad_domain = AD.DOMAIN.FULL.NAME

# Enumeration is discouraged for performance reasons.
# enumerate = true
```

This file needs to be protected so that only root can access it, or else `sssd` will refuse to start:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
sudo chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

Make sure the system will always know its fully-qualified DNS domain name; if necessary, add it to `/etc/hosts`.

Then restart the services that had their configuration modified:

```
sudo systemctl restart chrony.service
sudo systemctl restart smbd.service nmbd.service 
sudo systemctl start sssd.service
```

Now you should already be able to use `kinit` to perform initial Kerberos authentication with the AD. Do it as root using an AD user account that has the necessary permissions to add new systems to the domain:

```
sudo kinit Administrator
```

Verify that you actually got a Kerberos authentication ticket:

```
sudo klist
```

Now you should be able to use this command to actually join the AD domain:

```
sudo net ads join -k
```

If this command completes successfully, you should now be able to query the user account information of AD users using Linux commands:

```
getent passwd some-AD-username
```

As new users can be added to AD at any time, you'll need to set up a mechanism that will auto-generate a home directory for any AD user at login time if it doesn't already exist. Add this line to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, *directly after the `session required pam_unix.so ...` line*:

```
session    required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
```

The `override_homedir` line in `sssd.conf` will determine the pathnames of the AD users' home directories.